# ProjectName-Swift issue - Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios13, sign-in-with-apple

I'm now using Swift class in my existing Object-C project to integrate sign in with apple.In my Swift class, I'm using ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding delegate. However, when ProjectName-Swift.h is generated, an issue in ProjectName-Swift.h file shows that Can't find protocol declaration for 'ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding'. Works well in my pure swift project but can't work with mixed project I have.

ProjectName-Swift.h
[image: ppl]

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?